# Is Salt Cloud still supported for GCE

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, salt-stack, salt-cloud

I just discovered salt cloud and want to use it within my organization to add minion VMs to our cloud. I'm looking at it and it seems pretty old. Is this something that is still officially supported?

I was following the instructions to configure it listed here:
https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/topics/cloud/gce.html

When i create a service account I can't figure out what the instructions are saying. They seem out of date.

Alternatively, is there a way to combine terraform with Salt to deploy infrastructure and then automatically connect it to salt as a minion?

Answer (score 1):

It's seen [some commits in 2022](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/commits/master/salt/cloud/clouds/gce.py). However, it doesn't look like either the author from Google or Russell Tolle, listed as the maintainer has done much with it in a while.

There's an upcoming (2023) push to move a lot of these things out into [Salt extension modules](https://github.com/salt-extensions), so it's easier for the community to maintain modules that the core team simply doesn't have enough time to work on.